# How is corsOptions' origin value allowed to be different from the port that the app listens to for requests?

Tags: node.js, express, cors

I am writing a Node.js application that is using express and CORS. If I understand correctly, CORS allows/restricts requests made for a web server's resources. Furthermore, one is able to set the value of the "origin" parameter; the origin configuring the Access-Control-Allow-Origin CORS header, and only requests matching the value of origin will be allowed. For instance, if origin is set to "http://localhost:8081", only requests to "http://localhost:8081" will be allowed. However, an app that is created using express can listen on a specified port for requests, such as GET, POST, etc. This is specified by doing app.listen(PORT, ...). From what I understand, the port specified by CORS's origin parameter and the port that is listened on by the app can be different. Why is this? I thought only requests made from the specified CORS origin port will be allowed, and not any other port(s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CORS allows your nodejs server program to decide whether it should honor requests from web pages hosted from your server -- your origin -- and from pages hosted *other servers.*

So if the incoming origin is `https://cybercreep.example.com/` you might choose to reject it, but if it is from `https://sweetwestern.example.com:8081/` you might accept it.

That's why the allow headers let you specify an arbitrary origin. If you're filtering by origin, your CORS handler might look up the origin presented by a request in some sort of allow-list.